# Gridlines Above 3D Scatter Plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

When making a 3D scatter plot with matplotlib I cannot seem to control whether the axes are above or below the plot.  For example the following code will always have the x and y axes above the plot if ax1.elev < 0

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

fig = plt.figure('Test')
X = np.random.rand(1,100)
Y = np.random.rand(1,100)
Z = np.random.rand(1,100)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')

ax1.scatter(X,Y,Z)
ax1.view_init(-10,45)
```

Is it possible to force the x and y axes and the gridlines and planes to be below the plot even though ax1.elev < 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take as an example the code of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042129/changing-position-of-vertical-z-axis-of-3d-plot-matplotlib) (thanks [crayzeewulf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1062948/crayzeewulf)). Except for the z-axis, we do it for the x- and y-axis

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

fig = plt.figure('Test')
X = np.random.rand(1,100)
Y = np.random.rand(1,100)*10
Z = np.random.rand(1,100)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')

ax1.scatter(X,Y,Z)
ax1.view_init(-10,45)

tmp_planes = ax1.zaxis._PLANES 
ax1.xaxis._PLANES = ( tmp_planes[3], tmp_planes[2], 
                     tmp_planes[1], tmp_planes[0], 
                     tmp_planes[5], tmp_planes[4])

ax1.yaxis._PLANES = ( tmp_planes[3], tmp_planes[2], 
                     tmp_planes[1], tmp_planes[0], 
                     tmp_planes[5], tmp_planes[4])

view_1 = (25, -135)
view_2 = (-10, 45)
init_view = view_2
ax1.view_init(*init_view)
```

[image: Change_axes_pos]