# Two Z axes for 3D plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot using `plot_trisurf`, using the following code :

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(X1,Y1,Z1)
ax.plot_trisurf(X2,Y2,Z2)
```

The scale of Z1 and Z2 is different by several magnitudes.

How do I share the X and Y axis, but not the Z ?

In 2D I had the function "twinx()", but I can't find a solution for 3D.

Comment: Do `twinx`/`twiny` work in 3D? If they do, one possible workaround could be to pass the Z data as X or Y and then set the view and label the axes appropriately.

Comment: I tried something like `ax2 = ax.twinx().twiny()`, It didn't work, just got strange error. It doesn't feel like the right direction to solve the problem.

Comment: You may want to write function that emulates twinx but write it for the z axes since twinx/y don't work in 3D iirc.

Comment: @GlobalTraveler I'm not sure how to do what you suggested...

Comment: The twinx/y functions add an invisible axis to the axes. In order for this to work in 3D you have to write a custom class that overwrites the rendered similar to what happens [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042129/changing-position-of-vertical-z-axis-of-3d-plot-matplotlib).

Comment: It's an overkill, I hope there is a "normal" solution ..

Comment: Did you find a solution or did you end up overwriting the renderer?

Comment: it's a bad idea to have twin z axies because it won't make things clearer. twin axes in 2D is implemented because we just have left and right, and it's compact to compare. In 3D, why not put two trisurf side by side, simple and easy to compare. I never see people present their 3D data in twin z axes way:(