# Julia v1 - How to change the vertical axis position 3D plot?

Tags: matplotlib, 3d, julia

I'm doing a 3D plot in Julia and I get the following chart:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2Xb5.png)

with this code

```
Plots.pyplot()
fig1 = Plots.surface(x, y, z, ylabel=L"\kappa",xlabel=L"\phi", 
zlabel=L"Y^i_2",background_color = :white, zrotation=90, xrotation = 0, 
yrotation = 0,camera = (60, 50))
```

I would like to have both the xaxis and yaxis starting from zero at the same corner. Therefore, I would need to move the vertical (z) axis. Essentially, I would like to be able to generate these figures

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLACZ.png)

In Python, it can be done (as explained here  [Changing position of vertical (z) axis of 3D plot (Matplotlib)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042129/changing-position-of-vertical-z-axis-of-3d-plot-matplotlib)) but I can't figure out how to do it in Julia.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The z axis moves around when you rotate the plot, but you can get your y axis to intersect z at 0 by setting `ylim = (0,1)`. As for flipping the order of values on the y axis you can use `yflip = true`.

Comment: Sounds great - if it works for you it is considered best to accept my answer :-)